# Validation Framework for a WPF app (using MVP) and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wpf

I'm looking for a form validation framework that works best in both Windows (WPF using MVP) and Web (ASP.NET MVC).

I'm currently looking at three choices:

- Enterprise Library Validation Application Block
- http://www.codeplex.com/FluentValidation
- http://validationframework.codeplex.com

I like Fluent Validation as it looks a lot cleaner. The others, though, have been around longer.

Any other recommendations?

Comment: Doesn't ASP.NET MVC has built-in validation support? They are fairly easy to implement and seem to be solid enough for production use. In additional, quick google search shows http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/#MVC_Validation that you find helpful.

Answer (score 2):

In MVC apps I've found Fluent Validation very useful for more complex validations.  DataAnnotations are often enough for simple validations in MVC.